# httpclient class not found in android application

Tags: android, apache, http, android-studio, jar

Hello friends i make application which is based on web service so i added jar as below

```
apache-mime4j-0.6.jar
httpmime-4.0.1.jar
picasso.jar and so on..
```

When i configure my project with jar only **apache-mime4j-0.6.jar** is not getting to my project rest of all jar are access see my below image

[image]

Any idea how can i solve this? your all suggestions are appreciable.

Comment: try to use another android optimized http client like Okhttp, it's not an answer but a recommandation.

Comment: Have you updated sdk to v23, I think you have imported `android.jar` which is sdk  v23 (android 6.0) BTW this class removed from `android.jar`

Answer (score 1):

The IDE in your screenshot shows various class names in red that it can't find:

- HttpClient
- DefaultHttpClient
- HttpPost

These classes are provided by the [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/) project, not by apache-mime4j library.

Download the latest binary release of HttpComponents and extract the *.jar files within it to your `libs` directory.